# New Arduino Motor Shield Short Circuiting my board?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

I just got this today, plugged it in my arduino, and the arduino light starts dimming until you cannot see it any more over the course of 5 seconds. The Computer disconnects the arduino when the light is off (Ding Dong Sound). I found pulling the VIN Connector Jumper/Power Jumper will stop the short circuit and work, but that defeats the purpose, as the board wouldn't even powered.

Here is the video:
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEzPjXHXiL4)

Is the motor board broken? If so in what way? are the wires on the board simply broken? Is it due to bad soldering?(I checked solder, looks fine).

Arduino Model: Arduino UNO by Elegoo
Motor Driver Model: L293D Driver Board
[Ebay Listing For Item](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/L293D-Motor-Drive-Shield-Expansion-Board-for-Arduino-Duemilanove/162163308212?_trksid=p2050601.c100085.m2372&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140211132617%26meid%3D747824cb304b49b88d66ab2cc3ebd836%26pid%3D100085%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D162163308212%26clkid%3D2477980637705759209&_qi=RTM2247625)
(I tried using this with a MEGA also, would short it as well).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the name, model number, and a link for the  motor shield.  Otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: post is edited.

Comment: Does the board work ok if you pull that jumper and supply motor-power externally?  If so, maybe the Uno's power is marginal.  If not, maybe a chip or a capacitor is bad on the shield.  Looks like the chips are socketed, so you could take them out (sequentially) and see if shorting problem goes away.  If one of two LM293's is bad you could still use the other.  But before removing any chips or capacitors, get a really bright LED flashlight and carefully look all over the board for solder splashes, wire fragments, etc

Comment: I pulled all the chips out. They all work in the middle slot. The left and right slot will immediately short it, even if I place one

Comment: Have you tried it with nothing connected to the board and the jumper removed?  At the end of the day its a $2 board, from what you have described it has a fault and the seller would have a hell of a problem denying it.  Buy another from a different seller and see if you can get this one replaced although it might cost more to send back than its worth.  If you carry on testing it, trying to diagnose the fault you may trash you Arduinos.  Keep the board for spare parts, chances are you'll fry the chips. :)

Comment: Yep it's a 2$ chip. The problem is it takes 3 months to ship X_X

Comment: George, the flaw with a “all work in the middle slot” test is that the middle socket is wired for a 74HC595 shift register, vs LM293.  Note, for parts list of original Adafruit 74HC595 + 2 LM293 board  board, see [Adafruit motor shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/parts-list), from a 15-page tutorial on this type of board.  Also see Adafruit's mshieldv12schem.png schematic  that may allow you to check your board's wiring

Comment: I just checked. All 3 chips are identical. Is that a problem? The markings at the top are all 74HC595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jwpat7, I have discovered that the reason it is not working is that the seller has messed up and sent me 3 of the same chip, 74HC595N. After doing some research, I have purchased the LM293D Chips.

Comment: That's really horrible.  Though it's worth noting that the L293, even if you actually got them, isn't a great solution to begin with.  If you are facing down long shipping delays you might want to consider preemptively ordering a more modern solution overall rather than waiting for the L293's only to perhaps be dissappointed by them.  Especially at lower voltages something using a TB6612FNG or similar may be preferable.  Do note also that you really shouldn't be powering your motor drivers from the Arduino's logic supply or regulator.